# Question is off topic, where to put it or how to improve?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I just noticed that (after getting much valuable insight though the answers) this question was flagged as off topic:

[How can we explain CIDR notation with /24 and /32 to a manager?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1028435/how-can-we-explain-cidr-notation-with-24-and-32-to-a-manager?noredirect=1#comment1336801_1028435)

Before posting I tried to check the [help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), and found this (emphasis mine):

Server Fault is for questions about managing **information technology systems in a business environment**.

- managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or **networks**

After reading this I felt fairly confident that it was a good fit. I am not too interested in analyzing why/how it got closed, but am mostly curious on where to put it or whether it seens salvageable in a reasonable way.

---

What else did I check:
Later in the help center, a pointer is given to Super User for questions about 'general networking'. However from the [Super User help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), it is specified as such:

- personal and home computer networking

I think this question is more relevant for corporate networking than personal networking.

Answer (score 2):

If I had seen it, I probably would have closed it as being primarily opinion-based: how to explain something in a non-technical way is heavily dependent on the person you're explaining it to.

The reason the question got so many answers is that it showed up on the Hot Questions List, which made it more visible to people on other SE sites.  It's a known problem with the Hot Questions list that "bad" questions sometimes end up on it and get a lot of activity before they're shut down.  ServerFault doesn't get too many Hot Questions, so it doesn't come up that often here, but it has happened before.

(I don't mean your question is particularly bad - it's actually interesting - but it's not a good fit for ServerFault.)

Comment: Alright, I do not intend to change the question now as it already got several answers but for future reference: Suppose I would 'just' ask something like: "What is the meaning of /20 in CIDR notation." Would that be a decent fit, or does it still not feel right? (I would be asking someone to explain something to me, rather than asking directly how to do something)

Answer (score 0):

I closed the question because it is not related to managing a network.  Some sort of site dealing with pedagogy would probably be most appropriate for this question.